# "ImportError: No module named 'gspread'"

Tags: python, python-2.x

I installed gspread library and ran `pip install gspread` and followed all the instructions on [this page](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html). I've read many other threads on this issue and have checked that no file named gspread.py exists in my entire rapi 3b. I am running on python 2.7.9. My code never gets past

```
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import glob
import tkinter as tk
import json
import sys
import time
import datetime
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
```

At `import gspread`, it throws `ImportError: No module named 'gspread'`. If I delete `import gspread` it throws the same error on oauth2client; `ImportError: No module named 'oauth2client'`.

My suspicions are that I have it installed in the wrong place, but I am new to pi and do not know too much about paths.

Please help... Why is it throwing these errors when I have these libraries installed?

Comment: many times this is because you ran pip for python2 and are running the script with python3  or visa versa.

Comment: Hey @ChadG thanks for the quick response, I only have python 2.7.9 on the pi, so I don't think that it is that. Right?

Comment: Does `python3` then `import gspread` work?  If so gspread is installed for Python version 3.  Similarly `python2` then `import gspread`.

Comment: `python3` then `import gspread` doesn't work, throws the same `ImportError: No module named 'gspread'`. However, `python2` then `import gspread` throws no errors and returns nothing. Thanks for the response @joan

Comment: @LeoG It looks like you are running under Python 3 rather than Python 2 when you get the import error.  You need to check that you are actually invoking Python 2.

Comment: Thanks @joan, that worked. I'm now running the code with python 2 and at least the `import gspread` works. Of course changing versions caused a wave of other problems, but this fixed the gspread library. Thanks!

Comment: @LeoG  It might be simpler to use pip3 or similar to download a Python 3 version of gspread.

Comment: @joan Thanks, that worked great! pip3 installing both gspread and oauth2client solved all of my problems. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this problem.
I was running under python 3 but oauth2client and gspread were installed under python 2. To fix this, I ran `pip3 install` on gspread and oauth2client and all is running smoothly now.