# Adafruit_Nokia_LCD module on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-zero-w, python-2.x, adafruit

I'm stuck with this Adafruit module. I was able to install without errors on a Pi2, but when I tried to replicate on my Zero W the installation goes fine but then I cannot import the module ("Adafruit_Nokia_LCD module not find").

Raspian Strech in installed on both of them.

I installed the module with `sudo python setup.py install`, which gives the following output (I'm reinstalling it).

```
pi@WRM:~ $ sudo python Adafruit_Nokia_LCD/setup.py install
    running install
    running bdist_egg
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    reading manifest file 'Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    installing library code to build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg
    running install_lib
    warning: install_lib: 'build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

    creating build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg
    creating build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
    copying Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
    copying Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
    copying Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
    copying Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
    copying Adafruit_Nokia_LCD.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/EGG-INFO
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    creating 'dist/Adafruit_Nokia_LCD-0.2.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg' to it
    removing 'build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg' (and everything under it)
    Processing Adafruit_Nokia_LCD-0.2.0-py2.7.egg
    Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_Nokia_LCD-0.2.0-py2.7.egg
    Copying Adafruit_Nokia_LCD-0.2.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Adafruit-Nokia-LCD 0.2.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

    Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_Nokia_LCD-0.2.0-py2.7.egg
    Processing dependencies for Adafruit-Nokia-LCD==0.2.0
    Searching for Adafruit-GPIO==1.0.3
    Best match: Adafruit-GPIO 1.0.3
    Processing Adafruit_GPIO-1.0.3-py2.7.egg
    Adafruit-GPIO 1.0.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

    Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO-1.0.3-py2.7.egg
    Searching for spidev==3.2
    Best match: spidev 3.2
    Processing spidev-3.2-py2.7-linux-armv6l.egg
    spidev 3.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

    Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spidev-3.2-py2.7-linux-armv6l.egg
    Searching for Adafruit-PureIO==0.2.3
    Best match: Adafruit-PureIO 0.2.3
    Processing Adafruit_PureIO-0.2.3-py2.7.egg
    Adafruit-PureIO 0.2.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

    Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO-0.2.3-py2.7.egg
    Finished processing dependencies for Adafruit-Nokia-LCD==0.2.0
```

So seems everything ok, like the package is installed and available, but when I try to recall it on python shell...

```
pi@WRM:~ $ python
>>  import Adafruit_Nokia_LCD
>>  ImportError: No module named Adafruit_Nokia_LCD
```

**On the first output there's a warning about a missing folder** (precompiled libraries?), could be a hint about my situation?

The module is present on the right folder: (**no prob importing GPIO module**)

```
ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
Adafruit_GPIO-1.0.3-py2.7.egg       easy-install.pth
Adafruit_Nokia_LCD-0.2.0-py2.7.egg  spidev-3.2-py2.7-linux-armv6l.egg
Adafruit_PureIO-0.2.3-py2.7.egg
```

On the Pi2 the module works like a charm.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here: ["ImportError: No module named 'gspread'"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85866/importerror-no-module-named-gspread/89840#89840)

Solved using 'pip install Adafruit_Nokia_LCD/.'

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.